# VBA code to Google Script (Find difference in dates, find average, on Form Submit)

Tags: java, google-sheets

I am currently working on creating an app in google sheets from code I wrote in excel VBA. There are 2 sheets, one contains user submitted info. This info is dates and it populates row by row. There are 8 columns of dates (8 entries per row). The other sheet finds the difference in the dates (i.e. days in between), calculates and calculates an average.

I am having trouble with the script language and syntax but here is what I have so far:

```
    function calcValues() {

    //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   //ss.insertRowAfter(ss.getLastRow());
  //ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(),1,1,ss.getLastColumn()).copyTo(ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1,1));

  //spreadsheet variable declared
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 //FormResponses sheet declared as variable
 var sFR = ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("FormResponses"));
 //Last row on form response sheet
 var last = sFR.getLastRow();
 //Declare calcData sheet 
 var sCD = ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("CalcData"));

 //Loop to write values to CalcData sheet
 for( var i = 2; i < last; i++)
 if(sFR.getRange(i,1) !== 0){
  sCD.getRange(3, 1, 1, 8).copyTo(sCD.getRange(i+2,1))
  }
}

function FormSubmitUpdate() {
   //spreadsheet variable declared
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //FormResponses sheet declared as variable
  var sFR = ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("FormResponses"));
  //Last row on form response sheet
  var last = sFR.getLastRow();
  //Declare calcData sheet 
  var sCD = ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("CalcData"));

  //sCD.getRange("B4").setValue(sFR.getRange("C3").getValue()-    sFR.getRange("B3").getValue())
  //sCD.insertRowAfter(sCD.getLastRow());
  sCD.getRange(sCD.getLastRow(),1,1,sCD.getLastColumn()).copyTo(sCD.getRange(sCD.getLastRow()+1,1));
```

I currently have the formulas set in the cells and this code simply copies the formula down. calcValues counts how many user inputs there are and performs that many copies.

formSubmitUpdate copies the previous row down one row.

When I attempt to perform the subtraction of dates in the code I get a really strange number. I did some research and that is because of the millisecond date transformation.

I would like the subtraction and average to be found using code and not formulas in the sheet. I would also like it to update when a new userform is submitted.

If you can give me some code samples that will do what I am asking I would much appreciate it. I am a VBA guy and I would really like to learn this platform.

Thank you.

Comment: Please, any direction would be much appreciated!